# Code after Javascript for loop with Ajax not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is the "hello" alert at the end of this code not executing? Everything else is working fine, but the alert doesn't fire. What am I missing? PS, I am a beginner when it comes to Javascript...

```
$('.save_button').click(function(){
  var numItems = dataseries.length;
  var item;
  var sequence;
  var question = <%=@question.id%>;
  for (i=0;i<numItems;i++){
    var requestObj = {
      question_id: "<%=@question.id%>",
      user_id: "1",
    }
    item = $('.item_list li[data-seq='+i+']').attr('id');
    requestObj["item_id"] = item.toString();
    requestObj["x"]= dataseries[i][0][0];
    requestObj["y"]= dataseries[i][0][1];
    if (requestObj["item_id"]!="null"){
      var a = $.ajax({
        url: "<%=responses_path%>",
        data: requestObj,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'script',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert('error!');
        },
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-Token': '<%= form_authenticity_token.to_s %>'
        }
      });
    }
  }
  alert("hello");
});
```

Comment: As @dda mentioned, your developer console (Firebug, Safari/Chrome Console) should be spitting out errors somewhere.

Comment: Since there's obviously more code related to this than you are posting, if I put quote marks around the parts that definitely won't work isolated e.g. "dataseries.length", "item.toString();" it works fine! Obviously I get 404 errors on the ajax (not that I tested your code while connected to the internet anyway), but your code runs and I even get the alert box saying hello. Check and see if any other code interferes, also look out for errors in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with requestObj["item_id"] = item.toString();

In some instances, this was null and it was exiting with an error.  Thanks to all who responded.

Answer (score 0):

`var question = <%=@question.id%>;` should be `var question = "<%=@question.id%>";` (a string).

I tried it with the following additional code and it worked fine:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input type="button" class="save_button" value="Save" />
<ul class="item_list">
    <li id="item1" data-seq="0">item1</li>
    <li id="item2" data-seq="1">item2</li>
    <li id="item3" data-seq="2">item3</li>
</ul>​
```

---

```
// JS:
var dataseries = [
    [[1 /* x */, 2 /* y */]],
    [[2, 3]],
    [[3, 4]]
];
```